# Should we use definitive article `the` before `Sirik` in "Sirik water reservoir"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles

[Sirik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirik,_Iran) is the name of a city in Iran and so I believe that the usage of definitive article `the` is not needed before Sirik in the following sentences while Grammarly suggests me to add `the`

- This report aims to illustrate the methodology of measuring waves,
  currents and tides in the desired region for Sirik water reservoir.
- The purpose of these studies is to provide hydrodynamic and
  wave-based information for the design of Sirik water reservoir.
- The equipment for wave, current and tide measurements in Sirik study
  area

Comment: If the reservoir has an official name (the equivalent of 'Sirik Reservoir' in your language), it doesn't need an article. 'Study area' doesn't look like an official name, so I would probably use _the_ before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether or not *Sirik water* or *Sirik water reservoir* is the name of the reservoir.

If it is the name, then it should not have an article (but each word should be capitalised in English).

But if that is not the name of the reservoir, (it either has a different name, or is unnamed) then *Sirik* is a descriptor, and it requires an article: "the *which* water reservoir?" "The *Sirik* water reservoir".

The latter seems more likely to me, but I can't tell for sure.

One other point: *water reservoir* is not idiomatic except in contexts where there could be another kind of reservoir, eg inside an engine. An artificial lake used as the water supply for a place is referred to as a *reservoir*, not a *water reservoir*.